# How to add unique random values to the column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to add 1000 unique random values to the column AgentID to the table agents.

I have used Upsert to ignore the duplicate values. What I have done so far:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Generate_random;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Generate_random()
BEGIN
    Drop table if exists ai_training.`Agents`;
    CREATE TABLE ai_training.`Agents`(AgentID int PRIMARY KEY);

    SET @first = 1;
    SET @last = 1000;

    WHILE(@first <= @last) Do
        INSERT INTO ai_training.`Agents` VALUES(
                                                    FLOOR(RAND()*(2900000-2800000+1)+2800000)
                                                )
                                                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE AgentID = FLOOR(RAND()*(2900000-2800000+1)+2800000);
        SET @first = @first + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$


DELIMITER ;

CALL Generate_random();

Select * from ai_training.`Agents`;
```

The problem is I need 1000 unique agentid's and this code is generating 1000 - the repeated ones. So, if it finds 6 repeated ids it returns 994 rows and not 1000.

Is there any way I can achieve this?
Can't change the random ID generation part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [information function `ROW_COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) to check whether a row was actually inserted or not, and increment the counter accordingly.

The [documentation states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> With `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values.

So:

```
WHILE(@first <= @last) DO

    INSERT INTO ai_training.`Agents` 
        VALUES(FLOOR(RAND()*(2900000-2800000+1)+2800000))
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE AgentID = AgentID;
        
    IF ROW_COUNT() = 1 THEN
        SET @first = @first + 1;
    END IF;
    
END WHILE;
```

Note that I changed the action on duplicate key to a dummy update rather than re-assigning a new random value; this makes things a little less expensive when a collision happens.

Comment: `SET @first = @first + ROW_COUNT();` :) And INSERT IGNORE is more clear then ODKU I think.

Comment: @Akina: `ROW_COUNT()` *might* return `2` as well... (although, not in the above code.

Comment: While using INSERT IGNORE only 0 or 1 is possible in output.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Generate_random()
BEGIN
    Drop table if exists ai_training.`Agents`;
    CREATE TABLE ai_training.`Agents`(AgentID int PRIMARY KEY);
    SET @last = 1000;
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ai_training.`Agents`) < @last DO
        INSERT IGNORE INTO ai_training.`Agents` 
        VALUES
        (FLOOR(RAND()*(2900000-2800000+1)+2800000));
    END WHILE;
END
```